# Dropzone.js AMD inside Backbone view events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, dropzone.js

I'm using [Dropzone.js AMD module](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#toc_2) in application built with Backbone and Require.js. Dropzone object is being created inside render() function of Backbone view. I'd like to create an event, that would load Dropzone.js reference and than remove some files from it.

MyView module:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'dropzone'
  ], function($, _, Backbone, Dropzone){

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $('.products'),
  events: {
    'click .erase_dropzone_file': 'eraseDropzoneFile',
  },
  initialize: function(){
  Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    init: function() {
      this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
        console.log("uploaded");
      });
      }
    };
  },
  render: function(){
        myAwesomeDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone"); 
  },
  eraseDropzoneFile: function(e){
  files = myAwesomeDropzone.files;
  ...

});
  return MyView;
});
```

*Uncaught Error: No Dropzone found for given element. This is probably because you're trying to access it before Dropzone had the time to initialize. Use the `init` option to setup any additional observers on your Dropzone.*

I've also tried two more ways how to manage it, but both returned some error...

**1.**

```
render: function(){
this.myAwesomeDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone");
},
eraseDropzoneFile: function(){
files = this.myAwesomeDropzone.files;
}
```

*Cannot read property 'files' of undefined.*

**2.**

```
render: function(){
window.myAwesomeDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone");
},
eraseDropzoneFile: function(){ 
files = window.myAwesomeDropzone.files;
}
```

*No Dropzone found for given element. This is probably because you're trying to access it before Dropzone had the time to initialize. Use the `init` option to setup any additional observers on your Dropzone.*

Comment: Could you post the shim configuration (assuming you're using require.js 2)?

Comment: Since I'm using Dropzone.js as AMD module, there is no need to use shim method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dropzone tries to attach itself to any given `.dropzone` element when initialising. So make sure to set the configuration: `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;` as soon as the script is loaded. *(This has to happen before the `DOM READY` event fires, otherwise Dropzone might be faster than you and already tried to discover all dropzones.)*

When Dropzone does not auto discover, it will not use the options set in `Dropzone.options`. You have to provide them directly then.

So remove your `initialize` function, and change your render function to this:

```
this.myAwesomeDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone", {
  init: function() {
    this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
      console.log("added file");
    });
    this.on("success", function(file) {
      console.log("successfully uploaded file");
    });
  }
});
```

You should then be able to access `this.myAwesomeDropzone` in `eraseDropzoneFile`. Instead of accessing the `this.myAwesomeDropzone.files` Array directly, you might consider using `this.myAwesomeDropzone.getAcceptedFiles()` instead.